# A bass singer question

Tags: vocal-range, bass-voice

So I'm 15 and I'm able to hit a F2/E2 almost daily and in the mornings I've been able to hit D2/C#2 but I want to be able to get a C2 in my chest range for a while now. It would be very helpful if you were honest about what my future chest range could be.

Comment: You'll know by the time you're 40. :P I gained a whole tone over a similar period & that hasn't changed since.

Comment: When did your voice start changing?

Comment: Almost impossible to say. If you're still growing, that should make a difference.

Comment: If you want to sing for your whole life, I strongly suggest getting some professional lessons. Injuries are a risk for all musicians, but I think singers might have the most risk of injury that can change their voice permanently. If you have a teacher, apologies - I’m assuming not because I would expect them to be able to discuss your question with you.

Comment: This might not help -- but have you asked your relatives what their experience was, and when they stopped growing?

Comment: @aparente001 - I'll warn you that my mother says that she "wrecked her voice" a fairly long time ago, quite possibly before I or maybe even any of my siblings were born (fairly impressive given that my oldest sibling is more than 10 years older than me). She has indicated that she can no longer sing as high as she used to be able to. In contrast, since high school, I have lost my ability to sing the highest note in "The Phantom of the Opera" (watch me fail auditions for Christine right there) but not the second highest note.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - Bummer!  Have you at least gained a note or two at the bottom of your range? / I've never been a serious singer, but I do enjoy singing for fun; I have lost a couple notes right in the middle -- frustrating!  I think it's because in 2000 I moved to an area where apparently there were a lot of allergens that I was sensitive to, because I had SEVEN bouts of laryngitis in one year.

Comment: @aparente001 - I did gain some notes at the bottom; my A below the C below Middle C is now fairly reliable. I start losing it at the G# below that and I generally cack the G below that vocal fry-style.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say anything with certainty, but if you are now able to reach C# in the morning it might very well possible that you’ll be able to get a decent low register with time. You body will grow until about 21, so all of this will change. But in the end the low end is limited by technique and by the length of your vocal chords. The vocal chords might still grow, which might give you more low range, and technique can be trained. The best thing for you would probably to get lessons if you are able to, to train your low voice.